# How to get dynamic content without using Remark/Grey Matter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Stack is nextJS/react/typescript. I have a bunch of blog posts that I can dynamically set routes for no problem. However, I want to build some pages that do not use markdown. I haven't had much luck finding any good code examples. It seems like all of them use Remark/Grey Matter. I've been trying to reverse-engineer [this official example](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/blog-starter-typescript) but with no luck. So far, I can get work/index.tsx to map through all of the case studies, but I can't get it to route to the correct page. I'll save you code examples because it's so noodley from me debugging. code examples are basically several different versions of the example's code but without markdownToHtml stripped. I figure the solution is more of a specific technique than a block of code.

File Hierarchy:

```
_case-studies/
   │   caseStudyA.tsx
   │   caseStudyB.tsx
   │   caseStudyC.tsx
pages/
   │   work/
   │   │   index.tsx
   │   │   case-studies/
   │   │   │    [case-study].tsx
lib/
   │   api_case-studies.tsx
types/
   │   caseStudy.tsx
```

**EDIT (CLARIFICATION):**

The pages all have unique content as in it's not your typical passing of props to a [case-study] where the layout looks the same but I do something like {caseStudy.title} to simply update the title.

Okay, so, for now let's totally scrap the idea of markdown and pretend I never mentioned it. My new file structure is as following:

```
– lib/
    – api_case-study.tsx
– pages/
    – work/
        – index.tsx
        – [case-study]
        – case-studies/
             – ExampleA.tsx
             – ExampleB.tsx
             – ExampleC.tsx
```

On the index.tsx it would loop through all the case-studies. I can get it to do that now and get all the slugs and link to them, but I can't get it to return the title prop and I can't get the page itself to render without just loading the predefined layout of [case-study]. Does that make sense?

**EDIT 2 (Code Example):**

Here's the current state of my code, plz be gentle: [github gist](https://gist.github.com/jordanlambrecht/ac28b88ca4960d11f1ae408e567e6919)
*note:* I switched the naming conventions from 'case-study' to 'project' since the original post

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on what exactly you're trying to achieve, possibly with an example? Are you trying to mix markdown with non-markdown files for the same path-slug?

Comment: Sure thing. It boils down to mapping through all the pages in case-studies and making them pages. So, for example, on my work page i'd like to have links to all of the case studies in a list, and also somehow be able to grab their title, category, etc. The goal is to have it done automatically so I don't need to update the work page every time I add a new case study

Comment: Let's say you'd have a setup with markdown files like ```data/posts/```, you could use Node's ```fs``` package to map through all the different files and also generate the static paths for /case-studies/[case-study].tsx this way, but since you don't use markdown you probably fetch the metadata of the posts (slug, title, category etc.) from some server inside ```getStaticProps``` to generate the different ```[case-study].tsx``` pages  right? You can fetch the data source that stores all your posts inside ```index.tsx``` and get all the titles/slugs in there, or am I missing something?

Comment: @maxeth I think we're close. Sorry if I'm not explaining this correctly– I'm still learning and a lot of these concepts are pretty advanced for me.

Comment: @maxeth I updated the original post with some clarification for you. I'm going to simplify my code a bit and put that in the post as well so I'm making more sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try to export constants like `title` from your pages inside `/case-studies/`, but then inside your `getStaticPaths` in `api_project.tsx` you can't really access those variables inside `getProjectBySlug` because you do not export them like `export const title = "title"` (`getStaticProps` is used to fetch data to build the page, not to export props or anything like that).

I assume you want to fetch this metadata dynamically, so if you don't want to use gray-matter and exporting variables isn't really an option since you'd need to use dynamic JS imports which would be an overkill, I'd advise you to either use a free and hosted CMS like contentful and then store and fetch the project metadata in there, or simply create a directory like `/data/case-studies-meta.json` with a setup like:

```
[
  {
    slug: "ExampleA",
    title: "Title of Example A"
  },
 {
    slug: "ExampleB",
    title: "Title of Example B"
  }
]
```

Assuming you have the two Pages `ExampleB.tsx` and `ExampleA.tsx` inside `case-studies`.

And then import it inside your `api_project.tsx` file:

```
const ProjectMeta = require("./data/case-studies-meta.json"); // adjust path to directory structure
```

and inside your `getProjectBySlug`, you can now look up the metadata based on the slug you're passing to it. Keep in mind that you'll need to ensure that the slug inside `/data/case-studies-meta.json` is the same as the actual file-name of the case study `.tsx` page(s):

```
ProjectMeta.forEach((entry) => {
   if(entry.slug.toLowerCase() === slug.replace(/\.tsx$/, '').toLowerCase(){
      items.title = entry.title;
      // or make the items a let and do items = {...post} to copy all keys
   }
})
```

This should work, but it's not really optimal since you need to remember to update the slug inside `data/case-studies-meta.json` each time you rename/delete/add a new page inside `case-studies`.